# How to instal Perfex CRM on siteground server with temporary domain name provided by siteground

Tags: php, crm

I want to instal a PHP scrip by the name of Perfex CRM and its addons i upload the files in the public folder and extra it and once i reach to login part it says host name is incorrect as usually it should be localhost please help

Answer (score 0):

Well its been solved i have uploaded the file and its working